# Print CSV from a python list

Tags: python, csv

So I have this small python script that I'm using to validate whether or not a folder contains csv files. I have it working so far but I'm trying to print the CSV file from the result list of csv files to the console.

```
import os
import logging
import csv

logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

files = []
source = '/Users/username/source_folder'
files = checkFile(source)

if len(files) != 0:
    for i in files:
        with open(i, newline='') as file:
            for row in csv.reader(file):
                print(row)

def checkFile(directory):
    result = []
    if len(os.listdir(directory)) == 0:
        return result
    else:
        for file in os.listdir(directory):
            if file.endswith('.csv'):
              result.append(file)
            else:
                continue
    return result
```

I keep getting this error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
```

So the result is something like this: `['test_01.csv','test_02.csv']`
But I would like to read the each file from the list to the console.

`test_01.csv`

```
id,first_name,last_name,phone,
1,joe,black,555555555
2,jack,flash,1111111111
```

`test_02.csv`

```
id,first_name,last_name,phone,
1,joe,black,555555555
2,jack,flash,1111111111
```

Comment: Use `os.path.join(source, i)` in the `open()` function.  Or `result.append(os.path.join(directory, file))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`os.listdir(...)` returns the file/sub-folder names only (not the full paths). Unless the csv files are in your current working directory, you will need to combine their names with the directory, e.g. with `os.path.join(...)`:

```
def checkFile(directory):
    result = []
    if len(os.listdir(directory)) == 0:
        return result
    else:
        for file in os.listdir(directory):
            if file.endswith('.csv'):
              result.append(os.path.join(directory, file))
            else:
                continue
    return result
```

Comment: Note also that `os.path.splitext(...)` is safer than `string.endswith(...)` as it is technically possible (if a bit weird) to have a directory that ends with ".csv".